# Kubernetes doesnt schedules the pods on the worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I  have the following code for pod creation. I have two nodes one master and another node is worker node, I am creating two pods I need one pod to be scheduled on the master and the other pod on the worker node. I have not specified for pod second testing1 to be scheduled on a worker node because by default pods are scheduled on worker nodes. But the second pod testing1 is also scheduled on the master node.

Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: test
   labels:
      app: test
spec:
   containers:
     - name: test
       image: test:latest
       command: ["sleep"]
       args: ["infinity"]
       imagePullPolicy: Never
       ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
    nodeSelector:
      node_type: master_node
    tolerations:
     - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
       effect: NoSchedule

kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: testing1
   labels:
      app: testing1
spec:
   containers:
     - name: testing1
       image: testing1:latest
       command: ["sleep"]
       args: ["infinity"]
       imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Thanks help is highly appreciated in solving this issue.

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodeAffinity / antiAffinity to solve this.

Why would you assign pods to a master node?

The master nodes are the control plane for your k8s cluster which may cause a negative impact if the pods you schedule on the master node consume too much resources.

If you really want to assign a pod to a master node I recommend you untaint 1 master node and remove the NoSchedule taint and then assign a nodeAffinity to this single master node unless you really need to run this on all your master nodes .

Answer (score 0):

When the Kubernetes cluster is first set up, a Taint is set on the master node. This automatically prevents any pods from being scheduled on this node. You have enabled scheduling pods on master - because you labeled it to make pod `test` run on master. So `kube-scheduler` will took master node under consideration while scheduling other pods.
For every newly created pod or other unscheduled pods, kube-scheduler selects an optimal node for them to run on, also master node if it is not set NotSchedule. Read more about [node-selection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler-implementation).

It means that you also have to configure worker node and pod `testing1` to make it possible to deploy this pod on specific worker node.

Different options of scheduling pods on specific nodes except `NodeSelector`:

1. instead of  `nodeSelector`  you can add  [`affinity:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)  under  `spec:`  section:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        matchExpressions:
        ...
```

Add the `nodeSelector` to your pod:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
...
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations: |
          [
            {
              ...
            }
          ]
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        ...
    […]
```

2. instead of  `nodeSelector`  you can add an annotation like below:

```
scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/affinity: >
  {
    "nodeAffinity": {
      "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
        "nodeSelectorTerms": [
          {
            "matchExpressions": [
              {
               ...
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Take a look: [pod-deployment-on-master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999756/how-to-force-pods-deployments-to-master-nodes).

Keep in mind that `NoSchedule` will not evict pods that are already scheduled. So if you want to test and make changes firstly delete deployment/pods and after labeling/tainting etc redeploy them.

**Note for future:**

If you allow a rogue pod running on a master node to access/hijack Kubernetes functionality not normally accessible to pods on non-master nodes there's always the possibility of someone hacking access to a pod/container and thereby gaining access to the master node.
If you run a rogue pod on your master node that disrupts the master components, it can destabilize your entire cluster. Clearly this is a concern for production deployments, but if you are looking to maximize utilization of a small number of nodes in a development / experimentation environment, then it should be fine to run a couple of extra pods on the master.